# What is Sqlite used for?

Tags: sqlite, connection

I don't know how authoritative this is but I found this:

http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=PerformanceConsiderations

and it doesn't seem good to have a lot of connections to sqlite.  This seems to be bad for the web and most applications that have more than a few users.  I'm having a hard time thinking of what sqlite would be used for when you don't need that many connections.  Every program I can think of needs users, lots of them sometimes, so what would I use a database for that doesn't allow that many connections?  I thought about prototypes but why would I use that when I can just connect to a larger database?  Embedded apps maybe?

Thank you.

EDIT:  Thanks everyone.  I look at the page recommended below but an confused about something:

[Under appropriate uses for sqlite it has:](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Situations Where SQLite Works Well

•Websites

SQLite usually will work great as the database engine for low to medium traffic websites (which is to say, 99.9% of all websites). The amount of web traffic that SQLite can handle depends, of course, on how heavily the website uses its database. Generally speaking, any site that gets fewer than 100K hits/day should work fine with SQLite. The 100K hits/day figure is a conservative estimate, not a hard upper bound. SQLite has been demonstrated to work with 10 times that amount of traffic.

Situations Where Another RDBMS May Work Better

•Client/Server Applications

If you have many client programs accessing a common database over a network, you should consider using a client/server database engine instead of SQLite. SQLite will work over a network filesystem, but because of the latency associated with most network filesystems, performance will not be great. Also, the file locking logic of many network filesystems implementation contains bugs (on both Unix and Windows). If file locking does not work like it should, it might be possible for two or more client programs to modify the same part of the same database at the same time, resulting in database corruption. Because this problem results from bugs in the underlying filesystem implementation, there is nothing SQLite can do to prevent it.

A good rule of thumb is that you should avoid using SQLite in situations where the same database will be accessed simultaneously from many computers over a network filesystem.

The Question:

I'm going to show my ignorance here but what is the difference between these two?

Comment: why did I get a close on this so fast?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's good for situations where you don't have access to a "real" database and still want the power of a relational db. For example, Firefox stores a bunch of information about your settings/history/etc in an SQLite database. You can't expect everyone that runs firefox to have MySQL or postgre installed on their machine.

It's also perfectly capable of running relatively-low traffic, read-heavy websites. The performance of it is overall very good, it's more than the large majority of websites need for their traffic levels.

Answer (score 38):

This is answered well by sqlite itself : [Appropriate use of sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

```
Another way to look at SQLite is this: 
SQLite is not designed to replace Oracle. It is designed to replace fopen().
```

Answer (score 10):

I also find that using SQLite is good for getting a prototype application together pretty quickly without the overhead of having a seperate DB server or bogging a development environment with an instance of MySQL/Oracle/Whatever.

Also easy to pick up and move the database to a different machine if you need to.

Answer (score 9):

It's often used for embedded applications.

It can be very handy to use a database like storage when you have no access to a database service. So SQLite is used since it's just a file you store somewhere.

Answer (score 4):

The iPhone uses it for call history, SMS messages, contacts, and other type of data.  Like Ólafur Waage said, good for embedded applications on mobile device because it's lightweight.  I have used it also on stand alone applications.  Easy to use and available on most platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Think about simple client or desktop apps that could make use of a db, like as a poor example, an address book. Rather than bundling a huge db engine like mysql or postgre with your deliverable, sqlite is very lightweight and easy to include with your finished app.

Answer (score 3):

This [FLOSS Weekly podcast episode](http://twit.tv/floss26) talks with the creator of SQLite and covers among other things goes over the type of things you would use it for.  Everything from file systems for mobile phones to smallish web sites.

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest terms, SQLite is a public-domain software package that provides a
relational database management system, or RDBMS. Relational database systems are
used to store user-defined records in large tables. In addition to data storage and management,
a database engine can process complex query commands that combine data
from multiple tables to generate reports and data summaries. Other popular RDBMS
products include Oracle Database, IBM’s DB2, and Microsoft’s SQL Server on the
commercial side, with MySQL and PostgreSQL being popular open source products.
The “Lite” in SQLite does not refer to its capabilities. Rather, SQLite is lightweight
when it comes to setup complexity, administrative overhead, and resource usage.

For detail info and solution about SQLite visit the link below:

http://blog.developeronhire.com/what-is-sqlite-sqlite/

Thank you.

Comment: The URL is now dead.

Answer (score 0):

What the above two answers say. Expanding slightly on Chad Birch's answer, its teh calls to the SQLite db, and a rather poor implementation of sync() that causes FF3 to be so slow in linux.